# Redshift CONVERT_TIMEZONE Issue

Tags: sql, type-conversion, amazon-redshift

I am facing an issue with the time conversion.

Whenever I tried to change the time to timestamp. It does not work. 
I have tried many of functions from http://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/redshift/latest/dg/Date_functions_header.html

But still a single function did not convert the date time to timestamp. An eg. I need date time `(2017-12-11 23:38:11)` as timestamp `(1513036800)` format.

Can you please guys tell me the exact function to convert that?

Also I have tried to use `CONVERT_TIMEZONE` function. 
It works fine, whenever I passed the static date inside this like: `CONVERT_TIMEZONE('GMT','GMT -1','2017-12-11 23:38:11')`

But if I change the date with my variable name, I am getting an error message:

> "ERROR: function convert_timezone("unknown", "unknown", character varying) does not exist HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts."

- Can you guys tell me function to convert the date into timestamp?
- Can you guys tell me reason of the above error while passing the dynamic variable?
- I want to add timezone and date together and then to get the timestamp value of that, is that possible?
- Dateadd function gives the same error while passing the dynamic variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per error message it looks like your timestamp is stored in a varchar column. You have to change the column to timestamp or convert the value on the fly to be able to use timestamp functions. I suggest the first because it has better performance. Redshift doesn't support column data type alteration, so to do this you have to recreate the table DDL with `timestamp` data type for time columns, insert data to the new table and replace the old table with it.

As for dynamic conversion, it's like this:

```
EXTRACT('epoch' FROM CONVERT_TIMEZONE('GMT','GMT -1',your_column::timestamp))
```

you just don't need to use `::timestamp` part if you convert the column

Comment: Hi Alex,

Thanks for help. Yes it works fine now without changing the column data type.

Can you tell me about the reason of usage "-1"  timezone. It is working opposite right now.  I want to use it as "+1" to get the exact time.

Like if you check select pg_timezone_names(); function.
"GMT -1" converted the time to add one hour in plus.

- Is there any specific reason of that !


Any help !
Looking forward to you again !

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Please ans if you can 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47868132/redshift-extract-function-issue

Comment: Ok. I tried to change my saved timezone to negative like this

EXTRACT('epoch' FROM CONVERT_TIMEZONE(replace(timezone, '+', '-'),date_time::timestamp))

Then i get " Invalid operation: Timezone name or abbrev not recognized." error.

if i used static 
EXTRACT('epoch' FROM CONVERT_TIMEZONE('GMT','GMT -1',date_time::timestamp))

Then it works fine.

As i know, first parameter is optional and it was working fine. without adding the first parameter. But now using replace function and some other condition. It is giving an error. 

Any idea !