# Redshift Extract Function issue

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

While using this query:

```
 SELECT date_time 
 FROM test_table 
 where EXTRACT('epoch' FROM CONVERT_TIMEZONE(replace(timezone, '+', '-'),date_time::timestamp)) >= 1513036800 
   and EXTRACT('epoch' FROM CONVERT_TIMEZONE(replace(timezone, '+', '-'),date_time::timestamp)) <= 1513555200 
 limit 10
```

I am getting this error:

An error occurred when executing the SQL command:

```
[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Invalid data
Details: 
 -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Invalid data
  code:      8001
  context:   Invalid format or data given: 0000-00-00 00:00:00
  query:     1909217
  location:  funcs_timestamp.cpp:219
  process:   query1_59 [pid=25572]
  -----------------------------------------------;
1 statement failed.

Execution time: 0.63s
```

I am unable to use "Extract" function two times in a single query.
I have tried to use "Between" as well. but that did not work.

If I remove one of any extract query from the date range. Then it would work.

Comment: Seems pretty obvious to me: `0000-00-00 00:00:00` is not a valid timestamp. Why are you storing timestamps in a varchar column?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name 

Well, my value was saved in the that type datatype already. But now it is working fine by filtering the vlaues bases on 0000.

BTW thanks.

Comment: You should fix your data model and change those columns to a proper `timestamp` type - then you wouldn't be able to store invalid timestamp values in that table in the first place. And you could properly index that column so that you don't have to convert it back and forth to a number just to query a timestamp range

Comment: i usually get that issue after importing mysql data as its very common for mysql to have those timestamps